# What level spell is Erupting Earth from Elemental Evil?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Erupting Earth is listed as a 3rd-level spell (in the Druid list), but under Higher Level Casting, it says "At Higher Levels. When you cast this spell using a spell slot of 3rd level or higher, the damage increases by 1d12 for each slot level above 2nd."

Is it supposed to be a 2nd-level spell?

Answer (score 20):

### It is a 3rd level spell. It was updated in published Errata.

> Erupting Earth (p. 236). In the “At Higher Levels” section, 3rd level
>   is now 4th, and 2nd is 3rd

Source: https://dnd.wizards.com/sites/default/files/media/PotA-Errata.pdf